# Collecting users who reacted to a message using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to collect all users that have reacted to certain message.
My code

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
    console.log(reaction.emoji.users);
}
```

But it returns undefined. If I use "reaction.emoji" it returns

```
ReactionEmoji {
  reaction: 
   MessageReaction {
     message: 
      Message {
        channel: [Object],
        id: '371695165498458115',
        type: 'DEFAULT',
        content: 'bb',
        author: [Object],
        member: [Object],
        pinned: false,
        tts: false,
        nonce: '371695172469129216',
        system: false,
        embeds: [],
        attachments: Collection {},
        createdTimestamp: 1508689433217,
        editedTimestamp: null,
        reactions: [Object],
        mentions: [Object],
        webhookID: null,
        hit: null,
        _edits: [] },
     me: true,
     count: 1,
     users: Collection { '370300235030986752' => [Object] },
     _emoji: [Circular] },
  name: '✅',
```

I'm trying to get the `users: Collection { '370300235030986752' => [Object] },` part. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) it is just `reaction.users`:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
        console.log(reaction.users);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I though it was reaction.emoji.users.