# Embed buttons in Discord.js is possible?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I created a Discord bot a while ago which prints the date of the next episode for a given show using BetaSeries API, but when the bot encounters multiple results for a show, it display a list of shows returned by the API.

At this point my bot asks to write again the command with the ID of the show (displayed in the list), but I'm searching for a way to create my list with buttons, when clicked a button displays automatically the show information without writing the command with the ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, many bots use reactions in discord to simulate a button, by having the bot react to a message asking to select a option with different emojis (usually No 1, No 2, No 3 etc emojis), and getting whether the message was reacted to by a certain user.

See [Collecting users who reacted to a message using discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877312/collecting-users-who-reacted-to-a-message-using-discord-js/46877412) for more info on how to get reaction events.

Answer (score 7):

As of May 2021, Buttons are officially implemented in the discord API. At this point of time, there are [unofficial wrappers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons) that support adding buttons

[image: Custom Button]

**Update ( July 2021 ):**

Buttons will be a part of discord.js v13 and higher. Refer to this [PR](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/5674) to stay updated